# Whats the best way to deal with function in php?

Tags: php, class, session

I got a class user with a function that returns user info from a database

example:

```
class User {
   public function get userInfo() {
      return $users;
   }
}
```

An object of class user is made when the user logs in.

Now I need that function on other pages as well but whats the best way to do this?

Option 1:
   Create a object of class user and store that object in a $_SESSION variable?

Option 2:
   Take the function out of the class and put in a seperate php file?

Comment: `<? php include 'path/to/your/file' ?>`

Comment: if you have difficulties comparing approaches, just use a php framework and learn. seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Research how frameworks handle this. Using an [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) is usually the best way to dynamically load classes. [PSR-0](http://php-fig.org/psr/psr-0) represents a standard on how to organize classes and develop an autoloader.

Answer (score 1):

You should include the file using `include_once` or `require_once`. 
 
You should also study `Design patterns`, `MVC` or `Framework`.

Answer (score -1):

Of course option two and named to that file common.php